# 2 output CNN with training of 2nd output being based on 1st output

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am working on a multi label problem classifying images. I don't have enough data, so I am using transfer learning with CNN being feature extractor. As I have enough data for some of the classes, I have formulated problem in a way:

30 classes and 31st being "rest" of the images, so I can distinguish them.

The 31st rest class is mostly dragging my accuracy and other metrics down. I was thinking about creating multioutput network in Keras, where one output would be binary classification whatever it is "good" or "rest" image and the second would be trained only if the first would be classified as a good.

I do understand fact that I will need evaluate the second output too, as that's how computation graphs works, but is there an option how to tell the layer: Don't adapt on this bad example, based on input from another softmax?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand to an extent what you want to achieve. The way to go for this would be to train two models - first would be a binary classification 'good' vs 'rest' and the output of this model, if 'good' would have to be passed to the second model - 30 class output model. This is actually fairly common way to go about problems as yours.

I worked on a helmet detection problem earlier - I noticed that instead of detecting helmets, it worked better if I detected persons with one model and pass these boxes to a classification model - 'helmet' or 'no helmet'.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i just wanted to avoid ensemble due to performance reasons. As I am using a CNN as a feature extractor, I would still extract exactly same features from CNN for both output layers. I was thinking about adding the 0 or 1 from first layer to second features from the last non Dense layer and pass it to the second layer, however I am not sure whatever this would work in keras + if network would find the 0 or 1 in features as significant enough.

Comment: I think it should be possible if you create the whole network from scratch, but I have never tried doing this...